# find all possible combination sequences in a list of python

Tags: python, list, sequence

i have a list in Python

```
mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

where 0 is the start and 5 is the end.
I wish to know if there a way to create all possible sequences between 0 and 5 such as:

```
mylist1 = [0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
mylist2 = [0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
mylist3 = [0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
mylist4 = [0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
mylist5 = [0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
```

etc

Comment: The previous duplicate was completely wrong for this question. It's important to understand terminology properly in order to do research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use itertools.permutations

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [2]: l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [3]: tuple(itertools.permutations(l))
Out[3]: 
((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4),
 (0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5),
 (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3),
 (0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4),
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), like this:

```
import itertools
gen = itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print gen.next()  # prints (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
print gen.next()  # prints (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5)
print gen.next()  # prints (1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6)
```

Keep doing it until `StopIteration` is raised.